# Is there an easy way of highlighting a region on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Other than drawing a polygon in Google Maps API, is there a way for me to get the "Northwest Washington DC" region on a Google map? When I search this area in Google maps itself, it has a nice highlighting effect which I like to replicate in my own website.

The issue with drawing the polygon is that I wouldn't really know how to get the correct LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path!

Comment: You found the solution? If yes please share. Some websites stores the path as a polyline in there DB. Dont know how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Google Geo Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html)

> A geochart is a map of a country, a continent, or a region with areas
>   identified in one of three ways:
>
> - The region mode colors whole regions, such as countries, provinces,    or states.
> - The markers mode uses circles to designate regions that    are scaled according to a value that you specify.
> - The text mode    labels the regions with identifiers (e.g., "Russia" or "Asia").

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is definitely not going to be a chart. The map will need to have several other functionality like any Google maps on top of the highlighted area which I can take care of on my own.